Correct format of Apple auto-renewable subscription expires_date
As the title states, I'm looking for the correct format of the Apple auto-renewable subscription "expires_date".
The "expires_date" field comes from App Store receipt json data.
for example:
       [{
            "quantity": "1",
            "product_id": "test2",
            "transaction_id": "1000000472106082",
            "original_transaction_id": "1000000472106082",
            "purchase_date": "2018-11-13 16:46:31 Etc/GMT",
            "purchase_date_ms": "1542127591000",
            "purchase_date_pst": "2018-11-13 08:46:31 America/Los_Angeles",
            "original_purchase_date": "2018-11-13 16:46:31 Etc/GMT",
            "original_purchase_date_ms": "1542127591000",
            "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-11-13 08:46:31 America/Los_Angeles",
            "is_trial_period": "false",
            "expires_date" : "2023-05-24 18:01:31 Etc/GMT"
        }]

I'm using:
@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
I see generally see dates like:
2023-05-24 18:01:31 Etc/GMT
This appears to work most of the time. However, there are cases where it appears to be failing, generally, but not always I see more failures from iOS devices in the UK.  I don't know what the date string looks like in those cases, unfortunately, as this code is being performed on the device.
There is no information on the apple developer site as to the correct format.  There is a deprecated document that states its RFC3339 date format.  However, this is not correct.  It is also not ISO8601 format.
BTW, here's basically the code I'm using.
 NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV";
 formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
 
 NSDate* expireDate = [formatter dateFromString:expireDate];

I then compare it to now with a date created like:
NSDate* nowDate = [NSDate date];
if(([nowDate compare:expireDate] == NSOrderedDescending) ||
   ([nowDate compare:bufferDate] == NSOrderedSame))
{
    //the subscription has expired
    retVal = true;
}

Like I said a vast majority of the time the format I provided works, but occasionally it does not. So I suspect an issue with the format of the expires_date field.

You don't say where you are obtaining this date from, but are you looking for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter?language=objc ?
